Require is not defined after Vite build
I'm currently using Vite to build my React app. I use react-comment-section
After I used vite build and deploy it to Firebase hosting. I always get this error: required is not defined

And I've found that this error comes from this react-comments-section package 
This is my vite.config.js I've tried transformMixedEsModules and commonJs but both of them don't work:
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import commonjs from "vite-plugin-commonjs";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), commonjs({
    filter(id) {
      if (id.includes('node_modules/@pmhieu/react-comments-section')) {
        return true;
      }
    },
  })],
  define: {
    global: {},
  },
  build: {
    commonjsOptions: { transformMixedEsModules: true }
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ["@pmhieu/react-comments-section"],
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      src: "/src",
    },
  },
});

What is the correct way to build my app and this package?

I would just make a PR request to replace this require which should not even be here in the first place... You could also patch on your side.

@Arkellys I change the required line to: "import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid'" and built the comment package again, but it says  Error: 'v4' is not exported by node_modules\uuid\index.js, imported by src\components\InputField\Index.tsx. How to resolve this mate?
